# OR in INNER JOIN ON clause

Tags: sql-server

I have some problem with ERP system.

I found problem is query with INNER JOIN.
Query (JOIN) look like this:

```
INNER JOIN nz__finanse fin2 ON ( 
  fin1.nzf_id <> fin2.nzf_id 
  AND 
  ( 
    spfin.nzs_iddlugu = fin2.nzf_id 
    OR 
    spfin.nzs_idsplaty = fin2.nzf_id 
  ) 
) 
OR 
( 
  fin1.nzf_id = fin2.nzf_id 
  AND 
  spfin.nzs_iddlugu = fin2.nzf_id 
  AND 
  spfin.nzs_idsplaty IS NULL 
)
```

If I delete one of condition, query works fine, but with both conditions (and OR) I have to wait several minutes to result.

I can't modify query so I have question:
is it possible to some optymalisation this query (for this OR in conditions)?

Thanks.
Regards.

full query (result in serval minutes):

```
SELECT POZ1.dko_konto      AS dko_Konto, 
       FIN1.nzf_typobiektu AS nzf_TypObiektu, 
       FIN1.nzf_idobiektu  AS nzf_IdObiektu, 
       FIN1.nzf_numerpelny AS nzf_NumerPelny, 
       Roznica = CASE WHEN FIN1.nzf_typ IN (39, 42, 18, 20) THEN (Round( CASE 
                 WHEN 
                 FIN1.nzf_typ 
                 IN (39, 40) THEN FIN1.nzf_wartoscpierwotna ELSE 
                 FIN1.nzf_wartosc END, 
                 2 ) - dbo.Fninsmuldiv( dbo.Fnwartoscrozrachunkownadzien( 
                 FIN1.nzf_id, 
                 '20171231', CASE WHEN FIN1.nzf_typ IN (39, 40) THEN 
                 FIN1.nzf_wartoscpierwotnawaluta ELSE FIN1.nzf_wartoscwaluta END 
                 ), 
                 FIN1.nzf_kurs, 
                 FIN1.nzf_liczbajednostek, 2 ) - Sum( dbo.Fnfin_wartoscwpln( 
                 FIN2.nzf_kurs, 
                 FIN2.nzf_liczbajednostek, CASE WHEN FIN2.nzf_id = 
                 SPFIN.nzs_idsplaty 
                 THEN 
                 SPFIN.nzs_wartoscwaluta ELSE SPFIN.nzs_wartoscwalutadlugu END ) 
                 ) ) 
                 ELSE -(Round( CASE 
                 WHEN FIN1.nzf_typ IN (39, 40) THEN FIN1.nzf_wartoscpierwotna 
                 ELSE 
                 FIN1.nzf_wartosc END, 2 ) - dbo.Fninsmuldiv( 
                 dbo.Fnwartoscrozrachunkownadzien( 
                 FIN1.nzf_id, '20171231', CASE WHEN FIN1.nzf_typ IN (39, 40) 
                 THEN 
                 FIN1.nzf_wartoscpierwotnawaluta ELSE FIN1.nzf_wartoscwaluta END 
                 ), 
                 FIN1.nzf_kurs, 
                 FIN1.nzf_liczbajednostek, 2 ) - Sum( dbo.Fnfin_wartoscwpln( 
                 FIN2.nzf_kurs, 
                 FIN2.nzf_liczbajednostek, CASE WHEN FIN2.nzf_id = 
                 SPFIN.nzs_idsplaty 
                 THEN 
                 SPFIN.nzs_wartoscwaluta ELSE SPFIN.nzs_wartoscwalutadlugu END ) 
                 ) )END 
                 + Sum( Isnull( 
                 CASE WHEN FIN3.nzf_typ = 45 THEN FIN3.nzf_wartosc WHEN 
                 FIN3.nzf_typ = 
                 46 THEN -FIN3.nzf_wartosc ELSE 0 END, 0 ) ) 
FROM   nz__finanse FIN1 
       INNER JOIN nz_finansesplata SPFIN 
               ON SPFIN.nzs_iddlugu = FIN1.nzf_id 
                   OR SPFIN.nzs_idsplaty = FIN1.nzf_id 
       INNER JOIN nz__finanse FIN2 
               ON ( FIN1.nzf_id <> FIN2.nzf_id 
                    AND ( SPFIN.nzs_iddlugu = FIN2.nzf_id 
                           OR SPFIN.nzs_idsplaty = FIN2.nzf_id ) ) 
                   OR ( FIN1.nzf_id = FIN2.nzf_id 
                        AND SPFIN.nzs_iddlugu = FIN2.nzf_id 
                        AND SPFIN.nzs_idsplaty IS NULL ) 
       LEFT JOIN nz__finanse FIN3 
              ON FIN3.nzf_idrozliczenia = SPFIN.nzs_id 
       INNER JOIN nz_rozdekret RD1 
               ON FIN1.nzf_id = RD1.nzd_idrozrachunku 
       INNER JOIN dkr_pozycja POZ1 
               ON POZ1.dko_id = RD1.nzd_iddekretu 
                  AND POZ1.dko_datadekretacji <= '20171231' 
       INNER JOIN pk_plankont PK1 
               ON POZ1.dko_konto = PK1.ko_nr 
                  AND POZ1.dko_idroku = PK1.ko_idrokuobrotowego 
       LEFT JOIN dkr__dokument DOK1 
              ON DOK1.dkr_id = POZ1.dko_iddokumentu 
       LEFT JOIN adr__ewid ADR1 
              ON ADR1.adr_id = FIN1.nzf_idadresu 
WHERE  RD1.nzd_idroku = 3 
       AND PK1.ko_id IN ( 14966 ) 
       AND FIN1.nzf_data <= '20171231' 
       AND SPFIN.nzs_data <= '20171231' 
       AND FIN1.nzf_typ IN ( 17, 18, 19, 20, 
                             39, 40, 41, 42, 
                             45, 46 ) 
GROUP  BY FIN1.nzf_id, 
          FIN1.nzf_typobiektu, 
          FIN1.nzf_idobiektu, 
          FIN1.nzf_iddokumentauto, 
          FIN1.nzf_typ, 
          FIN1.nzf_korekta, 
          FIN1.nzf_data, 
          FIN1.nzf_numerpelny, 
          FIN1.nzf_tytulem, 
          ADR1.adr_symbol, 
          ADR1.adr_nazwa, 
          FIN1.nzf_transakcja, 
          FIN1.nzf_terminplatnosci, 
          FIN1.nzf_wartoscpierwotna, 
          FIN1.nzf_wartoscpierwotnawaluta, 
          FIN1.nzf_wartosc, 
          FIN1.nzf_wartoscwaluta, 
          FIN1.nzf_splata, 
          FIN1.nzf_splatawaluta, 
          FIN1.nzf_kurs, 
          FIN1.nzf_liczbajednostek, 
          FIN1.nzf_idwaluty, 
          POZ1.dko_konto, 
          POZ1.dko_kwotawn, 
          POZ1.dko_kwotama, 
          DOK1.dkr_nrpelny, 
          FIN1.nzf_zrodlo, 
          RD1.nzd_status 
HAVING Sum(CASE 
             WHEN FIN3.nzf_id IS NULL THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) = 0 
       AND CASE WHEN FIN1.nzf_typ IN (39, 42, 18, 20) THEN (Round( CASE WHEN 
           FIN1.nzf_typ 
           IN (39, 40) THEN FIN1.nzf_wartoscpierwotna ELSE FIN1.nzf_wartosc END, 
           2 ) - 
           dbo.Fninsmuldiv( dbo.Fnwartoscrozrachunkownadzien( FIN1.nzf_id, 
           '20171231', 
           CASE WHEN 
           FIN1.nzf_typ IN (39, 40) THEN FIN1.nzf_wartoscpierwotnawaluta ELSE 
           FIN1.nzf_wartoscwaluta 
           END ), FIN1.nzf_kurs, FIN1.nzf_liczbajednostek, 2 ) - Sum( 
           dbo.Fnfin_wartoscwpln( FIN2.nzf_kurs, FIN2.nzf_liczbajednostek, CASE 
           WHEN 
           FIN2.nzf_id = 
           SPFIN.nzs_idsplaty THEN SPFIN.nzs_wartoscwaluta ELSE 
           SPFIN.nzs_wartoscwalutadlugu END ) ) ) 
           ELSE -(Round( CASE WHEN FIN1.nzf_typ IN (39, 40) THEN 
           FIN1.nzf_wartoscpierwotna 
           ELSE FIN1.nzf_wartosc END, 2 ) - dbo.Fninsmuldiv( 
           dbo.Fnwartoscrozrachunkownadzien( FIN1.nzf_id, '20171231', CASE WHEN 
           FIN1.nzf_typ IN (39, 40) THEN 
           FIN1.nzf_wartoscpierwotnawaluta ELSE FIN1.nzf_wartoscwaluta END ), 
           FIN1.nzf_kurs, FIN1.nzf_liczbajednostek, 
           2 ) - Sum( dbo.Fnfin_wartoscwpln( FIN2.nzf_kurs, 
           FIN2.nzf_liczbajednostek, 
           CASE 
           WHEN FIN2.nzf_id = SPFIN.nzs_idsplaty THEN SPFIN.nzs_wartoscwaluta 
           ELSE 
           SPFIN.nzs_wartoscwalutadlugu END ) ) )END + Sum( Isnull( CASE WHEN 
           FIN3.nzf_typ = 45 THEN 
           FIN3.nzf_wartosc WHEN FIN3.nzf_typ = 46 THEN -FIN3.nzf_wartosc ELSE 0 
           END, 0 
           ) ) <> 0
```

modified query (delete one of part alternative in INNER JOIN - result in servat seconds):

```
SELECT POZ1.dko_konto      AS dko_Konto, 
       FIN1.nzf_typobiektu AS nzf_TypObiektu, 
       FIN1.nzf_idobiektu  AS nzf_IdObiektu, 
       FIN1.nzf_numerpelny AS nzf_NumerPelny, 
       Roznica = CASE WHEN FIN1.nzf_typ IN (39, 42, 18, 20) THEN (Round( CASE 
                 WHEN 
                 FIN1.nzf_typ 
                 IN (39, 40) THEN FIN1.nzf_wartoscpierwotna ELSE 
                 FIN1.nzf_wartosc END, 
                 2 ) - dbo.Fninsmuldiv( dbo.Fnwartoscrozrachunkownadzien( 
                 FIN1.nzf_id, 
                 '20171231', CASE WHEN FIN1.nzf_typ IN (39, 40) THEN 
                 FIN1.nzf_wartoscpierwotnawaluta ELSE FIN1.nzf_wartoscwaluta END 
                 ), 
                 FIN1.nzf_kurs, 
                 FIN1.nzf_liczbajednostek, 2 ) - Sum( dbo.Fnfin_wartoscwpln( 
                 FIN2.nzf_kurs, 
                 FIN2.nzf_liczbajednostek, CASE WHEN FIN2.nzf_id = 
                 SPFIN.nzs_idsplaty 
                 THEN 
                 SPFIN.nzs_wartoscwaluta ELSE SPFIN.nzs_wartoscwalutadlugu END ) 
                 ) ) 
                 ELSE -(Round( CASE 
                 WHEN FIN1.nzf_typ IN (39, 40) THEN FIN1.nzf_wartoscpierwotna 
                 ELSE 
                 FIN1.nzf_wartosc END, 2 ) - dbo.Fninsmuldiv( 
                 dbo.Fnwartoscrozrachunkownadzien( 
                 FIN1.nzf_id, '20171231', CASE WHEN FIN1.nzf_typ IN (39, 40) 
                 THEN 
                 FIN1.nzf_wartoscpierwotnawaluta ELSE FIN1.nzf_wartoscwaluta END 
                 ), 
                 FIN1.nzf_kurs, 
                 FIN1.nzf_liczbajednostek, 2 ) - Sum( dbo.Fnfin_wartoscwpln( 
                 FIN2.nzf_kurs, 
                 FIN2.nzf_liczbajednostek, CASE WHEN FIN2.nzf_id = 
                 SPFIN.nzs_idsplaty 
                 THEN 
                 SPFIN.nzs_wartoscwaluta ELSE SPFIN.nzs_wartoscwalutadlugu END ) 
                 ) )END 
                 + Sum( Isnull( 
                 CASE WHEN FIN3.nzf_typ = 45 THEN FIN3.nzf_wartosc WHEN 
                 FIN3.nzf_typ = 
                 46 THEN -FIN3.nzf_wartosc ELSE 0 END, 0 ) ) 
FROM   nz__finanse FIN1 
       INNER JOIN nz_finansesplata SPFIN 
               ON SPFIN.nzs_iddlugu = FIN1.nzf_id 
                   OR SPFIN.nzs_idsplaty = FIN1.nzf_id 
       INNER JOIN nz__finanse FIN2 
               ON ( FIN1.nzf_id <> FIN2.nzf_id 
                    AND ( SPFIN.nzs_iddlugu = FIN2.nzf_id 
                           OR SPFIN.nzs_idsplaty = FIN2.nzf_id ) )                  
       LEFT JOIN nz__finanse FIN3 
              ON FIN3.nzf_idrozliczenia = SPFIN.nzs_id 
       INNER JOIN nz_rozdekret RD1 
               ON FIN1.nzf_id = RD1.nzd_idrozrachunku 
       INNER JOIN dkr_pozycja POZ1 
               ON POZ1.dko_id = RD1.nzd_iddekretu 
                  AND POZ1.dko_datadekretacji <= '20171231' 
       INNER JOIN pk_plankont PK1 
               ON POZ1.dko_konto = PK1.ko_nr 
                  AND POZ1.dko_idroku = PK1.ko_idrokuobrotowego 
       LEFT JOIN dkr__dokument DOK1 
              ON DOK1.dkr_id = POZ1.dko_iddokumentu 
       LEFT JOIN adr__ewid ADR1 
              ON ADR1.adr_id = FIN1.nzf_idadresu 
WHERE  RD1.nzd_idroku = 3 
       AND PK1.ko_id IN ( 14966 ) 
       AND FIN1.nzf_data <= '20171231' 
       AND SPFIN.nzs_data <= '20171231' 
       AND FIN1.nzf_typ IN ( 17, 18, 19, 20, 
                             39, 40, 41, 42, 
                             45, 46 ) 
GROUP  BY FIN1.nzf_id, 
          FIN1.nzf_typobiektu, 
          FIN1.nzf_idobiektu, 
          FIN1.nzf_iddokumentauto, 
          FIN1.nzf_typ, 
          FIN1.nzf_korekta, 
          FIN1.nzf_data, 
          FIN1.nzf_numerpelny, 
          FIN1.nzf_tytulem, 
          ADR1.adr_symbol, 
          ADR1.adr_nazwa, 
          FIN1.nzf_transakcja, 
          FIN1.nzf_terminplatnosci, 
          FIN1.nzf_wartoscpierwotna, 
          FIN1.nzf_wartoscpierwotnawaluta, 
          FIN1.nzf_wartosc, 
          FIN1.nzf_wartoscwaluta, 
          FIN1.nzf_splata, 
          FIN1.nzf_splatawaluta, 
          FIN1.nzf_kurs, 
          FIN1.nzf_liczbajednostek, 
          FIN1.nzf_idwaluty, 
          POZ1.dko_konto, 
          POZ1.dko_kwotawn, 
          POZ1.dko_kwotama, 
          DOK1.dkr_nrpelny, 
          FIN1.nzf_zrodlo, 
          RD1.nzd_status 
HAVING Sum(CASE 
             WHEN FIN3.nzf_id IS NULL THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) = 0 
       AND CASE WHEN FIN1.nzf_typ IN (39, 42, 18, 20) THEN (Round( CASE WHEN 
           FIN1.nzf_typ 
           IN (39, 40) THEN FIN1.nzf_wartoscpierwotna ELSE FIN1.nzf_wartosc END, 
           2 ) - 
           dbo.Fninsmuldiv( dbo.Fnwartoscrozrachunkownadzien( FIN1.nzf_id, 
           '20171231', 
           CASE WHEN 
           FIN1.nzf_typ IN (39, 40) THEN FIN1.nzf_wartoscpierwotnawaluta ELSE 
           FIN1.nzf_wartoscwaluta 
           END ), FIN1.nzf_kurs, FIN1.nzf_liczbajednostek, 2 ) - Sum( 
           dbo.Fnfin_wartoscwpln( FIN2.nzf_kurs, FIN2.nzf_liczbajednostek, CASE 
           WHEN 
           FIN2.nzf_id = 
           SPFIN.nzs_idsplaty THEN SPFIN.nzs_wartoscwaluta ELSE 
           SPFIN.nzs_wartoscwalutadlugu END ) ) ) 
           ELSE -(Round( CASE WHEN FIN1.nzf_typ IN (39, 40) THEN 
           FIN1.nzf_wartoscpierwotna 
           ELSE FIN1.nzf_wartosc END, 2 ) - dbo.Fninsmuldiv( 
           dbo.Fnwartoscrozrachunkownadzien( FIN1.nzf_id, '20171231', CASE WHEN 
           FIN1.nzf_typ IN (39, 40) THEN 
           FIN1.nzf_wartoscpierwotnawaluta ELSE FIN1.nzf_wartoscwaluta END ), 
           FIN1.nzf_kurs, FIN1.nzf_liczbajednostek, 
           2 ) - Sum( dbo.Fnfin_wartoscwpln( FIN2.nzf_kurs, 
           FIN2.nzf_liczbajednostek, 
           CASE 
           WHEN FIN2.nzf_id = SPFIN.nzs_idsplaty THEN SPFIN.nzs_wartoscwaluta 
           ELSE 
           SPFIN.nzs_wartoscwalutadlugu END ) ) )END + Sum( Isnull( CASE WHEN 
           FIN3.nzf_typ = 45 THEN 
           FIN3.nzf_wartosc WHEN FIN3.nzf_typ = 46 THEN -FIN3.nzf_wartosc ELSE 0 
           END, 0 
           ) ) <> 0
```

in brief:
change:

```
INNER JOIN nz__finanse fin2 ON ( 
  fin1.nzf_id <> fin2.nzf_id 
  AND 
  ( 
    spfin.nzs_iddlugu = fin2.nzf_id 
    OR 
    spfin.nzs_idsplaty = fin2.nzf_id 
  ) 
) 
OR 
( 
  fin1.nzf_id = fin2.nzf_id 
  AND 
  spfin.nzs_iddlugu = fin2.nzf_id 
  AND 
  spfin.nzs_idsplaty IS NULL 
)
```

to:

```
INNER JOIN nz__finanse fin2 ON ( 
  fin1.nzf_id <> fin2.nzf_id 
  AND 
  ( 
    spfin.nzs_iddlugu = fin2.nzf_id 
    OR 
    spfin.nzs_idsplaty = fin2.nzf_id 
  ) 
)
```

or to:

```
INNER JOIN nz__finanse fin2 ON 
( 
  fin1.nzf_id = fin2.nzf_id 
  AND 
  spfin.nzs_iddlugu = fin2.nzf_id 
  AND 
  spfin.nzs_idsplaty IS NULL 
)
```

solving a problem.

Hence the question how to optimize this join (without is editing).

Comment: Please post an example of the slow query - don't make us guess

Comment: I'm sorry. Post is updated.

Comment: What I really meant was a MCVE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. In particular - the minimal bit, that is, show the difference with your top query.

Comment: As in, an example of "If I delete one of condition, query works fine, but with both conditions (and OR)" with regards to your top (simpler) query